# add node function changes index during function call in c

Tags: c, adjacency-list

I am trying to create an adjacency list for an undirected, weighted graph so I can run Dijkstra's and Kruskal's algorithms on and I'm running into an interesting problem. Whenever I try to add a second edge to a list index, it seems like it changes the list index to the new edge during the function call, erasing the previous edge list index was pointing to. (I think this person was having a similar problem but there isn't an answer for it: [How to create an adjacency list of a directed graph in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120088/how-to-create-an-adjacency-list-of-a-directed-graph-in-c)). Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Edge node
struct edge{
    int v1;                 // vertex it's coming from
    int v2;                 // vertex it's going to
    int weight;             // weight of edge
    struct edge *next;
}

const int MAX = 9;

void createAdjList(struct edge **list);
struct createEdge(int v1, int v2, int weight);
void addEdge(struct edge **list, struct edge newEdge);

int main(){
    struct edge *list = malloc(MAX * sizeof(struct edge));
    createAdjList(&list);
    ...
    return 0;
}
// creates the adjacency list
void createAdjList(struct edge **list){
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i)
        list[i] = 0;

    // first edge from vertex 0 to 1
    addEdge(list, createEdge(0, 1, 22));
    addEdge(list, createEdge(1, 0, 22));

// this is where the problem happens, when i call addEdge(list, createEdge(0, 2, 9)); 
// as soon as it enters addEdge, list[0] goes from pointing to the 0-1 edge to already
// pointing to this second edge, 0 to 2

    // second edge from vertex 0 to 2
    addEdge(list, createEdge(0, 2, 9));
    addEdge(list, createEdge(2, 0, 9));

    ...
}
// creates and returns an edge node
struct createEdge(int v1, int v2, int weight){
    struct edge newEdge;
    newEdge.v1 = v1;
    newEdge.v2 = v2;
    newEdge.weight = weight;
    newEdge.next = 0;
    return newEdge;
}
// adds the edge to the adjacency list
void addEdge(struct edge **list, struct edge newEdge){
// at this point, after the addEdge(list, createEdge(0, 2, 9)); call, list[0] is now 
// pointing to this new edge and Edge(0, 1, 22) is gone
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; ++i){
        // if edge vertex equals index i
        if(newEdge.v1 == i){
            // if list index is empty, place it at head and return
            if(list[i] == 0){
                list[i] = &newEdge;
                return;
            // else traverse to the end, place it and return
            }else{
                struct edge* curr = list[i];
                while(curr->next != 0)
                    curr = curr->next;
                curr->next = &newEdge;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. How can code in `main` call functions that have not been declared? And no library headers are included. Otherwise, reverse the sequence of the functions in the source code, so each has already been defined when it is called. Enable compiler warnings. Otherwise we have to ask stupid questions like "did you `#include` the library header?", and so on.

Comment: The `createEdge` function returns an instance of the structure. That structure is passed by value to `addEdge`. The `newEdge` parameter is a local copy of the structure. That local copy ceases to exist as soon as `addEdge` returns. So `list[i] = &newEdge` is not valid, it makes `list[i]` point to something that doesn't exist after `addEdge` returns.

Answer (score 0):

`list[i] = &newEdge;`

Here `newEdge` is a function parameter, which is the same as a local variable in that it is destroyed when the function `addEdge` returns.

So after `addEdge` returns, the list has a pointer that points to where `newEdge` used to be. Chances are the values of the edge are still there, and chances are that memory will be reused for something else the next time you call a function. In your case it happened to be reused to hold the next edge.

The solution would be to `malloc` some space to hold the edge in the list. Memory allocated with `malloc` can't be reused until you `free` it.